# What happens when response fails to reach the client in a token authenticated API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, access-token

This explains how [token authentication](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#about-token-management) works in rails when this lib is used.
[image]

> But, if this *(as shown in image below)* happens, should I sign-in again to get a new valid token that can be used for the next request? This doesn't seem so good as network failure might often happen; isn't there a simple "RETRY" way?

[image]

EDIT: The server would accept the retry request, if it reaches within 5 seconds since the previous one, essentially *treating it as a [batch request](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#about-batch-requests)*. However, this wouldn't help solve my problem.