# Which type of token auth is more secure for api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication, devise, token

I am confused if I should choose between [devise-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) *(issues new tokens for each request)* or [knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock) *(issues a json web token once and keeps using it till it expires or user signs in again)*

1. *Timing Attacks*: While one might say token authentication is vulnerable to timing attacks, their docs say they are securely comparing the tokens mitigating timing attacks as mentioned in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6). **Is it still flawed?**
2. *Network Failures*: Is there an advantage in issuing tokens for every request? And **what happens if network failures like the one mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276885/what-happens-when-response-fails-to-reach-the-client-in-a-token-authenticated-ap) happen**?
3. *Stealing Tokens*: If something like knock-JWT is used, what happens when someone somehow *(by intercepting in HTTP or even with HTTPS enabled using client side apps/extenstions to capture outgoing request headers)* steals the token? **Can they use it and get responses as given originally to that user?**
   Does the same happen when someone somehow steals a token issued by devise-token-auth? *(It doesn't make it harder because they can't keep using the token again: making a request using a stolen token help get new tokens, hence can infinitely be in contact with server, however, both of them canNOT be in contact, only one can while the token held by other is unusable - **is this an advantage or disadvantage?**)*

Is continuously issuing tokens possible in case of JWT and is it worth doing it? *(Like making the server issue a new token with a new expiry after each request)*

*PS: I just came across these two libs for Rails for effectively managing tokens integrating with devise. If there's a better one - which typically one would use for ecommerce like APIs - I'm open to using that.*

Comment: did u found solution of this? I am also in similar situation here